# Does this proof of the Boundedness Theorem contain a mistake?

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning, sequence-of-function

My course notes (mathematics BSc, second-year module in real analysis, unpublished) have a proof of the Boundedness Theorem which begins:
[image]

But does that sequence work? Here's my reasoning.

Let
\begin{aligned}
& D=[0,2], \\
& f:D\to\mathbb{R} \text{ be given by } f(x)=x \; \forall \; x \in D;
\end{aligned}
then
\begin{aligned}
\inf\{x\in D:f(x)>1\}
& = \lim_{h\rightarrow0}(1+h) \\
& = 1
\end{aligned}
but
\begin{aligned}
|f(1)|
& = 1 \\
& \ngtr 1
\end{aligned}
so the proposed sequence $(x_n)$ need not give a function value with the desired property $|f(x_n)|>n \; \forall \; n \in \mathbb{N}$ .

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Writing my comment as an answer, so this question can be deemed "answered".*

Your example is correct, the flaw in the proof can be fixed by replacing $n$ by $n + 1$ in the definition of $x_n$.